# HTML feature only works when launched as Live Server (or opened in Internet Explorer Mode)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, liveserver

I am migrating a functionality for importing Icons into powerpoint from an Internet Explorer based solution to a more modern solution, as the Internet Explorer is no longer available. For this I am currently implementing a WebView2 based approach.

For this I have an Icon2.html (and the code coming with it), which when opened as a File
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sklc7.png),
will not allow me to change the color of the Icon in the preview, [here the preview icon should be orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vorAQ.png).
The Html Page uses a modified version the [spectrum Color Picker](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum) for picking colors.

As the functionality was originally conceived for the Internet Explorer, the functionality works fine when launched in the Microsoft Edge using Internet Explorer Mode.
A peculiar thing is however, that when I use the VSCode Live Server Extension to launch the Icons2.html as a [Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYuBj.png), the color changes perfectly fine on a [modern Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY8PA.png).
I did test the Html with the Edge-, Firefox- and the Chrome Browser (as well as asking a colleague, the problem isn't local),so it does seem like the Live Server does something to help.

As I do not have much experience using Html, Javascript and CSS, hints on where to start looking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not all code for the web is programmed (and tested) to also work with URIs using the `file:` protocol syntax.

Your sample screenshots show that your problems arise when using a direct local file access:

```bash
C:\Users\....
# converts to
file:///C:/Users/....
```

The "Live Server" (as any other server) will enable you to use the `http:` protocol syntax, that natively is expected by web code.

The problem (I would not to call it a fault) is part of the programming of the "spectrum Color Picker", perhaps only of your customized version.

I would expect that some depending files are not found.

- Check the logs of your web browser's developer tools.
- Relative paths should be used.
- URI-analysis might be to lax. I.e. the `:` can be irritating in this context.
- Surely much more ....

Perhaps you should remember:
*The intention of web code is not live locally on a file system but on a web server. That such code might work in other context like using `file:`-URIs should be resembled as a welcome extra.*

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I found the limiting factor and it is the .getSVGDocument() method, which is disabled in newer Browsers using the `file:` format, as it grants access to the users Filesystem.